# How to add a list or dictionary as an SQL table entry?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, create-table

I have data from a JSON file to fill in SQL table entries. Most are self explanatory such as `Ints` or `Strings`. However, I have some data in the form of a list, or a dictionary, example:

List:

```
"Favorite_Things": ["Netflix", "Pizza"]
```

Dictionary:

```
"Time_Slots": {"1:00": 8, "2:00": 12, "3:00": 5}
```

I am unsure how to represent these in an SQL table, can you help give me an example to fill in these blanks?

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    USER_ID CHAR(56) PRIMARY KEY,
    AGE INT NOT NULL,
    FAVORITE_THINGS ??????
    TIME_SLOTS ??????
    EYE_COLOR CHAR(12) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a separate table, something like this:

```
create table userThings (
    userThingId int auto_increment primary key,
    userId,
    thingId int,
    constraint fk_userThings_userId foreign key (userId) references users(userId),
    constraint fk_userThings_thingId foreign key (thingId) references things(thingId)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new table for any array or dictionary fields, then have user_id in each of those tables linked back in the user table.

Here is what you will need to create:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    USER_ID CHAR(56) PRIMARY KEY,
    AGE INT NOT NULL,
    EYE_COLOR CHAR(12) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE USER_FAVORITE_THINGS (
    FAVORITE_THINGS_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    USER_ID CHAR(56),
    FAVORITE_THING CHAR(100),
    FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USER(USER_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE USER_TIME_SLOTS (
    TIME_SLOTS_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    USER_ID CHAR(56),
    TIME_SLOT_KEY CHAR(5),
    TIME_SLOT_VALUE INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USER(USER_ID)
);
```